Correct way to mocking of httpx response
I build API with Litestar, and I have several methods that internally call functions with asynchronous network requests.
# routs.py

class TokenController(Controller):

    @post("/check-token")
    async def check_token(self, data: SomeSchema) -> Response:
        try:
            token = data.token
            response = await get_token(token=token)
            response_json = json.loads(response.text)
            return Response(
                status_code=status_codes.HTTP_200_OK,
                content=SomeResponse(
                    idToken=response_json["idToken"],
                    refreshToken=response_json["refreshToken"]
                ),
            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise HTTPException(
                detail=e.detail, status_code=e.status_code, extra=e.extra
            )

# service.py

async def get_token(token: str) -> Response:
    url= "some-url"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = {
        "token": token,
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        return response

I'd like to write a test for the check_token function. How can I mock the internal get_token function?
UPD. I tried something like this:
# tests.py

@pytest.mark.asyncio
class TestTokenController:
    @mock.patch("app.service.get_token", new_callable=mock.AsyncMock)
    async def test_check_token(self, get_token_mock):
        my_mock = AsyncMock()
        my_mock.return_value = TOKEN_RESPONSE
        get_token_mock.side_effect = my_mock
        async with AsyncTestClient(app=app) as client:
            response = await client.post("/check-token", json=TOKEN_DATA)
            assert response is None  # I'll fix it later. Now I just examine the response

I'm expecting to receive TOKEN_RESPONSE in response, but I see that the response looks like a real response (moreover, if I turn the Internet connection off, then the test returns a 500 error). My mock doesn't participate in the test.
Dirs structure:
project
├── app
│   ├── token
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   └── service.py
└── tests
    └── tests_token
        └── test_routes.py


there is no get_token did you mean check_token? If so, how is this any different from mocking any other function?

thanks, but my question still stands, how is this any different from mocking any other function? Can you also mention what you tried and why that did not work

so I removed the other tags as its not really related to httpx or others. Can you try mock.patch("app.routs.get_token")

of course, i can, but it doesn't work, because get_token is located in service module, not routs

can you show how you are importing get_token in routs.py?

from app.service import get_token

did you try what I suggested?

do you mean mock.patch("app.routs.get_token")? this option I tryed

yes, that works for me, if not can you show your folder structure

project
├── app
│   ├── token
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   └── validators.py
│   └── service.py
└── tests
    └── tests_token
        └── test_routes.py

I don't know how to show structure correctly :(

can you edit in the question? comments don't support those

can you try mock.patch("app.token.routes.get_token")
